# flutter problem when update Xcode 12.5 and ios 14.5

Tags: ios, swift, flutter, cocoapods, cryptoswift

when Xcode updated the last version 12.5 when I build IOS app it failed because of flutter and pods Cryptoswift[image: image for the error]

I tried to pod update but it downloads 0.15.0 not the last version of Cryptoswift

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem was with flutter_pusher_client: ^0.3.1 and laravel_echo:
the packages not updated and they use an old version of Cryptoswift and get failed in build.

Comment: So what exactly was the solution? Dit you upgrade the flutter_pusher_client dependency?

Comment: Good, sounds like I can upgrade without issues then. Thanks for testing this out, bruh.

Comment: @JeroenBoumans I removed it for now and try to get another package.

Answer (score 3):

I ended up fixing flutter_pusher_client package to use most recent PusherSwift
https://github.com/heywhy/flutter-pusher-client/pull/23

Until package is up to date you can use updated version

```
@pubspec.yaml
 
     flutter_pusher_client:
            git:
              url: https://github.com/yfer/flutter-pusher-client.git
```

Comment: can you provide a version without null safety?